# Proving the sum of two finite cardinal numbers is finite

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, cardinals

I am trying to prove the following:

> If $m,n\in \omega$, then $m\oplus n<\omega$

My proof is as follows

Say wolog $m\in n$

Let 
$$f:(\{0\}×m)\cup (\{1\}×n)\rightarrow 2×\omega$$
$$f(t, p)=<t,p>$$

$f$ is 1-1 and not onto since there is no element in the domain that maps to $<1,n>$

Thus

$$m \oplus n < |2×\omega|=|\omega|=\omega$$

Is this correct? Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Just because you have a function which is 1-1 but not onto doesn't mean you have strict inequality of cardinalities.

Comment: $f(n) = 2n$ is not onto, but obviously $|\mathbb N| = |\mathbb N|$. This argument only works for finite sets.

Comment: Understood. So for any two cardinals, is there a way to prove inequality of the two by finding a mapping between them? Or is this done in a different way?